# Issues working with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

First of all I have read all previous answers on this topic but that didn't solve my problem.
When I installed cpu version of tensorflow on my windows 10 it worked fine but when I installed the gpu version I keep getting error message
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'**
in spyder on anaconda.
I have also tried updating the toolkit but that too didn't solve the problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtBns.png)

Comment: what steps are you using to install?  pip?  conda?

Comment: pip didn't work so I installed it using conda

Comment: with my reputation I can't add a picture right now but in short import tensorflow doesn't show error on anaconda promt while it shows error on spyder

Comment: Some things you might want to try https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6548. Also, did you install the NVidia CUDA drivers and everything required to run tensorflow on it in Windows? Also, the `tensorflow-gpu` module is different from the `tensorflow` module. Make sure to install the right one

Comment: yes I properly added all the paths also

Comment: Did you install `tensorflow` or `tensorflow-gpu`? The docs https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#installing_with_virtualenv state this specifically that the former is cpu support only

Comment: tensorflow-gpu.

Comment: Can you try installing with pip again, and confirm that the Python version you are running with is same as the Python that the pip you installed with is correlated to? So install with pip for Python3 and running with Python2 will not work. Or you might have multiple versions of Python3 or Python2

Comment: Also, your error message says that you can't import keras, not tensorflow. Have you installed keras? can you show the output of the command?

Comment: tried pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu

Comment: I think there is some problem activating tensorflow-gpu version on spyder

Comment: @ytpillai it says that no module tensorflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you did not activate the environment before launching Spyder.  You also may want to use conda to install Spyder into your tensorflow environment.

Try:

```
conda install -n tensorflow spyder
activate tensorflow
spyder
```

Comment: what is the name of the environment in which you are trying to run tensorflow on a gpu?

Comment: sorry I didn't get your question

Comment: Solved it by uninstalling tensorflow and reinstalling the gpu version again

Comment: Sometimes that's all it takes. Glad you figured it out. Did you reinstall CUDA libraries too or just NVIDIA drivers?